# How to Select Next row from table which has Working day flag

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as below with Working Day as a flag N for weekends and B for bank holidays. Now I want to select next working day like for example For 1st may Next working day will be the next row with Y as working day flag which will be 4th May. Could you pls suggest a SQl query to do that

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cumulative, conditional minimum:

```
select t.*,
       min(case when workingday = 'Y' then fulldate end) over (order by fulldate  rows between 1 following and unbounded following)
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3825daa3720b6fd9ca8ff1d2e5b4e29e) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This is not working.    Below is the result set.                                                                    2021-05-31 00:00:00.000 202105 22 B NULL
2021-05-30 00:00:00.000 202105 21 N NULL
2021-05-29 00:00:00.000 202105 21 N NULL
2021-05-28 00:00:00.000 202105 21 Y 2021-05-28 00:00:00.000
2021-05-27 00:00:00.000 202105 21 Y 2021-05-27 00:00:00.000
2021-05-26 00:00:00.000 202105 21 Y 2021-05-26 00:00:00.000
2021-05-25 00:00:00.000 202105 21 Y 2021-05-25 00:00:00.000
2021-05-24 00:00:00.000 202105 21 Y 2021-05-24 00:00:00.000

Comment: @RuhiAfreen . . . I misinterpreted the question -- thinking "get the current day if it is a business day".  But you want the next day.  I modified the answer and added a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery like this:

```
Select t.Fulldate, 
t.Period, 
t.ISOWEEK, 
t.WorkingDay,
(Select MIN(Fulldate) from sourceTable where Fulldate > t.FullDate and WorkingDay = 'Y') as NextWorkingDay
From sourceTable t
```

Comment: @RuhiAfreen If this solves your problem, the appropriate action to take is to mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
declare @dt         date='2021-01-01';

select min(FullDate) next_work_FullDate
from tTable
where FullDate>@dt
      and WorkingDay='Y';
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the conditions in the `WHERE` clause to filter the table, sort the remaining rows by date and pick the 1st row:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM tablename
WHERE Fulldate > '2021-05-01' AND WorkingDay = 'Y'
ORDER BY Fulldate
```

Or, if you want only the date:

```
SELECT MIN(Fulldate) Fulldate
FROM tablename
WHERE Fulldate > '2021-05-01' AND WorkingDay = 'Y'
```